# $_POST check against 'First Name' and security

Tags: php, post, input

So, I know how to check for empty fields and whatever else. 
I can't seem to figure out how to check for empty field, letters only, and make sure the default value from input is not being passed in a clean code.

I tried using the switch but became confused when it came to checking for empty.

Also, I used CSS to capitalize the disappearing default in the forms, so do I need to check with case sensitivity in mind?

Comment: You can check if a string only contains letters using the `ctype_alpha()` PHP function. For seeing if it's 'empty' (doesn't have any characters), you can use `strlen()`, which returns the length of the string. For the default text, the only way you have is to manually check the value. Basically: `if (isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] != "Enter your name" && ctype_alpha($_POST['name']) && strlen($_POST['name']) > 0) { /* do stuff */ } else { /* do stuff for invalid text */ }`

Comment: @AlejandroIván Incorrect, strlen on it's own can be mislead by having a single white space, which is not empty and returns a length. You will have to `echo strlen(trim($_POST['name']));` to get a proper length

Comment: Amazingly, PHP has a function called empty() that returns true if what's passed in is empty.  No need to use strlen()

Comment: @KevinM1 Again, a whitespace can change the return from false to true.. Either way, for a correct validation based if the string is empty or does contain characters/integers.. The value will have to be run through `trim()` to eliminate any false validations due to a white space

Comment: It's amazing how you guys help everyone. Thank you very much, I'm going to try it right now using all input

Comment: @DarylGill is correct, I just didn't say that function because it was a comment and not an actual answer, but `trim()` is mandatory in almost any case. I, personally, always use it. Anyway, `ctype_alpha()` is supposed to return `false` if there are spaces in the string, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])){
    $Temp_Value = trim($_POST['name']);
    $Error_Array = array();

    if (empty($Temp_Value)){
        $Error_Array[] = "Value Is Empty";
    }
    unset($Temp_Value);

    if ($_POST['name'] !== "Insert Default Text Here"){
        $Error_Array[] = "Please Insert text other than the default value";
    }
        if (count($Error_Array) !== 0){
            foreach ($Error_Array AS $Errors){
                echo $Errors."<br>";
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: that is way too much writing to cover everything

Comment: @user2689468 Updated to compare the value to the default text, also added a method for correct error reporting.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['firstname'])){
                      $fname = trim($_POST['firstname']);
                  }
                   if ($fname == "First Name"){
                    $errors[] = "bad entry";
                   }

Comment: that code doesn't work, i removed everything else to test and still passes default value as true

Comment: @user2689468 Update your question with the updated validations on your `$_POST[key]` with the default value

Comment: So I tested with  if(isset($_POST['firstname']) && ctype_alpha(trim($_POST['firstname']))){
                      echo "good";
                  }   else{
                    echo "bad";
                  }

Comment: default value passed as bad, if i type a name, it passed as good

Comment: It sees the white space between names in default value and returns false, so ctype_alpha won't work

Comment: @user2689468 The validations are checking if the default value is a cast type match to the array value. If you wish for the default value to be passed as good and anything else passed as bad then add a `!` after the opening parenthesis of the if statement. and if using `trim()` all white spaces will be removed.

Comment: YAY!!  Success                        if(isset($_POST['firstname']) && (trim($_POST['firstname'])) != "first name"){
                      echo "good";
                  }   else{

Comment: @user2689468 My mistake, about the string comparison, just noticed that after my previous comment

Comment: I did not want the default value to pass cause it is that javascript code that puts instruction inside input fields that appears and disappears, I didn't want someone just clicking submit without leaving their name

Comment: The culprit? Since I used CSS to text transform, I tried matching what I saw, but in html it is lowercase. That was the hangup.